Finding which column of a Google Sheet a value is in
I'm looking to see if there is a function which can help here on Google Sheets. I have one sheet with a list of 'names' (ID numbers in the actual data but generated a sample with names) and a second tab with a list of groups. I am hoping there is a way to work out which column or group from the second tab each name is in.
Example Sheet: 
I have tried match and lookups but neither seem to work for this. Ideal solution would end up looking like:
hopefully column B here but also happy with column C



Group 1
Group 2
Group 3
Group 4
Group 5




Lilia Jensen
Hasnain Mcbride
Lorna Brady
Jimmy Schneider
Yunus Carlson


Eleri Dorsey
Jonathan Adams
Lili Beck
Hafsa Bonner
Savannah Atkinson


Madeline Holland
Kamran Malone
Kelsie Bradshaw
Kurtis Reese
Mitchell Barr


Yuvraj Glover
Clifford Merrill
Natasha Turner
Ollie Zuniga
Sumaya Holden


Freya Casey
Magnus Case
Oakley Mccoy
Miguel Norris
Pablo Stone


Kieron Rios
Malik Campbell
Ted Mclean
Hayden Santiago
Amin Blake


Tia Hardy
Elaine Michael
Leland Fleming
Ela Pearce
Charles Medina


Gerard Pearson
Rosalind Kent

Ruth Hancock
Lorenzo Cabrera


Jared Conley
Jazmine Lucero

Tamzin Pena



Felicity Marsh
Kimberley Cole

Trinity Lang



Jerome Tate


Ruben Archer



Ayden Mccarty


Tiana Scott



Melody Lane










Column A
Column B
Column C




Lilia Jensen
Group 1
A


Tiana Scott
Group 4
D


Ela Pearce
Group 4
D


Leland Fleming
Group 3
C


Jazmine Lucero
Group 2
B





You may try:
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,xlookup(1,bycol(Groups!A:E,lambda(Λ,xmatch(Σ,Λ)^0)),Groups!A1:E1,))))



You may use (per row / drag down formula):
=LET(a,BYCOL(Groups!$A$1:$E,LAMBDA(col,IF(OR(BYROW(col,LAMBDA(element,element=A2))),index(col,1),""))),FILTER(a,a<>""))

Input
As mentioned before, this formula only works per row so you must drag down the formula to update parameters for corresponding rows. (Still working on how to improve the formula)

Output:

